How to make a color in three js
I have a problem, the color displayed in the element is not yellow, but gray with yellow
 export const CubeAnimation = () => {
      return (
        <Canvas
          camera={{ aspect: 2, far: 1000, fov: 45, near: 0.1, position: [0, 90, 50] }}
          style={{ background: 'black' }}
        >
          <pointLight color={0xffffff} intensity={1500} />
          <mesh position={[0,0,0]}  scale={[5,5,5]}>
             <sphereGeometry args={[1, 6, 6]} />
             <meshPhongMaterial color={0xffff00} emissive={0xffff00} /> // This element
           </mesh>
           <mesh position={[0, -3, 0]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
            <planeGeometry args={[500, 500]} />
            <meshPhongMaterial color={'black'} />
          </mesh>
          <OrbitControls enablePan enableZoom />
        </Canvas>
      )
    }

enter image description here
That's the color
Expected
enter image description here
